# Force load fglrx / emulate display

Tags: fglrx, headless, opencl

I want a headless machine (no display attached) for OpenCL calculation but `fglrx` drivers won't fully load until I attach a display to the VGA card.

The VGA (R9 290) doesn't have DAC (there are DP, HDMI, DVI-D, but no DVI-I or D-sub), so the "dummy plug" won't work.

Any ideas about how to forcefully load the drivers (so that they can do both OpenCL calculations and be tuned via ADL), disable this OS/driver behavior (energy saving and/or system stability concerns), or fake a display (make the GPU work to an emulated frambuffer or something which can act like a real display)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I will answer my own question with a dirty workaround. But at least it worked. I

1. Acquired a dead HDTV motherboard to connect a fake display via HDMI (one to the first VGA card, not all of them)
2. Installed TeamViewer (I really hate this, especially on Linux, but...) and made a remote connection
3. Opened a terminal with CTRL+ALT+T and issued these commands:

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0
   ./amd_fglrx_installer.run
   ```
4. went through the direct install method via the graphical installer (instead of building `*.deb` packages -> this is why SSH won't cut it and why I needed a graphical remote desktop)
5. Issued in the same terminal (where `DISPLAY=:0` remained active, repeat the `export` command otherwise):

   ```
   amdconfig --adapter=all --initial
   reboot
   ```

After Ubuntu booted, `cgminer` sees every `OpenCL` device and can monitor/control them via ADL. It runs slightly better on the Ubuntu 14.04 nightly than it did on Windows 8.1 (higher GPU/RAM clock rates are more stable and I can use higher concurrency parameters without running out of the system RAM).

Note that I need to start `cgminer` in a terminal windows inside the TeamViewer graphical remote desktop and also issue the `DISPLAY:=0` export in advance. It still doesn't work through SSH.

I am not sure if at least one of these steps are redundant but this is how I finally got it working. And to be honest, it's not exactly a headless machine now. I am not sure if I am free to remove the HDMI cable from the first VGA card now, or I need to keep that plugged in. I don't have the courage to mess everything up by trying. :)

I am still searching for a way to get rid of TeamViewer because it causes ~50% load on both CPU cores even when I do not connect any clients to the server. But `xrdp` doesn't seem to work at all with `fglrx` (I don't see the desktop, just a black background with an X as a cursor).

Also note that I used a nightly build. I think older stable versions will do just fine. I was just on a row of "try everything" and I ended up using this Ubuntu build when I accidentally got it working. You should consider that the latest stable driver from AMD I limited to kernel 3.11, and won't install with kernel 3.12, so I need to keep the earlier beta.